# making a cross-thread call to hide a form visual c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio, timer

*Update: Solution arrived since and is now accepted. Due to the clarity of the pseudo codes on this question the solution took only a few seconds. Trying to figure out the solution from the other seemingly "duplicate" questions took a lot of time already. I had the solution in 20 minutes from the moment I asked this question. So it is not a duplicate, probably the clearest of them all to date.*

While several similar questions have been asked on this, I was still not able to put together a working code from them. My main application is not on a form, but in a separate class that is a plugin and executed by a host application.

So while it seems a duplicate question it is not. Please read on.

I have my main class doing stuff. Then I have a form that displays information to the user. I need to hide this form when the user switches away from the application (host application loses focus).

I am using very limited APIs so the only methods I have at my disposal events triggered by the host application.

I created a timer that fires every 100ms and checks whether the user had the application in focus. And if not a command is sent to the form to hide itself.

The reason for this approach is because the host application loosing focus is just one of the many scenarios that I need to hide the form and I need to channel all these through the same exact method.

All works from within the rest of the classes (the `Hide()` method is called from the rest of the application no problem. 
But it does not work when the timer calls the `Hide()` method, because the timer is on a different thread when it fires. So the call becomes a cross-thread call.

The very specific question is that I need an exact sample code how to make this call from the timer event handler to the form's `Hide()` method thread-safe with `Invoke`.

Thanks.

This is the timer:

```
private void Controllel_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
    myTimer.Interval = 50;
    myTimer.Start();
}

public static System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
// This method checks different scenarios when the tool tip should be hidden and calls the hiding method
public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    FormHandler.Hide();
}
```

Then the "FormHandler" class:

```
public static class FormHandler
{
    private static Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

    public delegate void Form1HideEventHandler();
    public static event Form1HideEventHandler Form1Hide;

    public static void Hide()
    {
        if (Form1Hide != null)
        {
            Form1Hide();
        }

    }
}
```

Then the form's code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{   
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormHandler.Form1Hide += FormHandler_Form1Hide;
    }

    private void FormHandler_Form1Hide()
    {
        Hide();
    }
}
```

I would like to get a solution with exact code if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Found a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523878/getting-cross-thread-operation-not-valid

Comment: @Rob -- Thanks. That may lead me to a solution. But what is the exact code to use with the above pseudo code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void FormHandler_Form1Hide()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { FormHandler_Form1Hide(); }));
    }
    else
    {
        Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. And yes, it was **perfect** with your edit on adding the `else` part. I already had this when I applied your sample.

Comment: Just for *DRY*, I prefer to call self in the `InvokeRequired` part instead of repeating the same code as below... something like: `if(InvokeRequired) { this.Invoke(() =>  FormHandler_Form1Hide()); return; }` then in case the function gets longer you don't have to repeat your code

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead. That will invoke back onto the dispatcher thread.

Comment: That's the problem, I need to call the form from outside of the form. The reason is because the host application loosing focus is just one of the many scenarios that I need to hide the form and I need to channel all these through the same exact method.

Comment: Yes, but if you use that timer it will dispatch back onto the UI thread. The method doesn't matter, all that matters is the thread.